# Taylor's inequality for $x\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Using Taylor’s inequality, give an upper bound on the error of the approximation $f(x) = x\ln(x) \approx T_3(x)$ the interval$[1/2,3/2]$, where $T_3(x)$ is the third degree taylor polynomial about $x=1$.

I know that

$|f(x) - T_3(x)| \le M(x-1)^4/4!$, and $M = \max (f^{(4)}(x))$ in $[1/2, 3/2]$. So $f^{(4)}(x) = 2/x^3$ and the max is at $x=1/2$, thus

$|f(x) - T_3(x)| \le (x-1)^3/3$

Is this correct?

Comment: The upper bound that you've found depends of $x$. Try to find the maximum of $\frac {(x-1)^3}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The max is indeed at $x = 1/2$.

Thus your fourth derivative at this value should yield $2^4$, which is your value for $M$.

Substituting in this in the remainder equation yields $\frac{2}{3}|x-1|^4$ versus your value of $\frac{|x-1|^3}{3}$.

Continuing on to simplify, by looking at the interval from $[0.5,1.5]$, you can rewrite $|x-1| \le \frac{1}{2}$

Adding this in gives you a remainder of $\frac{2}{3}(1/2)^4 = 1/24$.

Thus $|f(x) - T_3(x)| \le 1/24$. Or in other words, the third Taylor polynomial is accurate within 1/24 on the interval $[0.5,1.5]$.

Not 100% on this answer as I actually solved it for a homework assignment and was here for a reference, just posting my solution. And I'm assuming there is an error as third degree Taylor polynomials are traditionally much more accurate than this although it may be a reasonable answer as there is an asymptote at $x=0$ for $\ln x$.

Comment: Try to learn $\LaTeX$. It's a great tool.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773). ref: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189